# if vs require - Predict the future challenge

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging

this is my first message here!

I've been trying to solve this challenge: https://capturetheether.com/challenges/lotteries/predict-the-future/, and I don't understand why I was able to solve it only using `require`.

I did all the necessary steps to solve the challenge, I will omit the code because is not directly related to my issue, but in a few words: I created an interface, a fallback and I called the challenge's address giving an input to `function lockInGuess(uint8 n)`, after that, I tried to call the `function settle()`*).

Here is my dilemma.

With this `require` code, after a couple of attempts I got lucky and `answer == myGuess` so the challenge got solved:

```
    function settle(IPredict _address) public payable {
        uint8 answer = uint8(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(blockhash(block.number - 1), block.timestamp)))) % 10;
        require(answer == myGuess);
        _address.settle();
    }
```

With this `if/else` code:

- when the else statement was true, so `answer != myGuess`, the tx was approved and the answer number of the unlucky attempts was stored in `uint8 public answerHashed`
- when the if statement was true, so `answer == myGuess` my tx failed, not allowing me to
  solve the challenge.
  e.g. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xbc0d7c19e77e9fd5284d96f018f1ae19e0b54b02a508f3d85e4b53006c36ee24

```
uint8 public answerHashed;

function settle(IPredict _address) public payable {
        uint8 answer = uint8(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(blockhash(block.number - 1), block.timestamp)))) % 10;
        if (myGuess == answer) {
            _address.settle();
        }
        else {
            answerHashed = answer;
        }
}
```

Is anyone able to tell me why? Thanks in advance!
If I wasn't clear enough in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/ropsten/0xbc0d7c19e77e9fd5284d96f018f1ae19e0b54b02a508f3d85e4b53006c36ee24 You ran out of gas, try again with a higher gas limit and it should work all fine :)